# Переменная реального времени.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Хочу проконсультироваться касательно следующей идеи.
Подскажите, как можно вызвать реальное время (к прим. по Гринвичу) и вложить его в переменную. 
Выглядит примитивно, но что-то типа этого:

```
var realTime = realTime();
```

Ну, я надеюсь, вопрос понятен. Надеюсь он адекватный, жду ответа.

Comment: В каком формате время должно быть?

Comment: 18 июля, 2017г.

Comment: Так это ведь дата, а не время

Comment: **var time = new Date();** Будет взято локальное время компа. А что вы подразумеваете под реальным временем?

Comment: @Cheg, вы правы, думал конкретика не столь важна.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Время по Гринвичу (GMT +1), как я понимаю, часто берут как образец международного времени. new Date(); - время компа клиента или моего?

Comment: @denisChunihin, это время компа, на котором выполняется скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вопроса не вполне очевидно, что именно требуется, но возможно, что-то в таком духе?

```js
let timeObj = {
  get currentTime() {
    return new Date();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="console.log(timeObj.currentTime)" value="Get time">
```

Здесь при каждом обращении к свойству `currentTime` объекта `timeObj` будет возвращаться текущее время.

Comment: стоит добавить, что таким образом получается только время установленное на компьютере, а не _реальное_ время